# How to build an asymmetric multi-party communication protocol?

Tags: c++, networking

I am implementing a c++ application which involves multiply users(for example. 128 users) with asymmetric roles(they all have different jobs). In such scenario, every user has to communicate with each other. Thus each pair of users need a bi-direction (virtual) communication channel between them.

There are three popular messaging patterns in this application.

1. Exchange: each user i has a message m_ij for user j != i to send. The length of m_ij is a public constant value. These messages m_ij are independent and have no relation with each other. This is something like "everyone has something for everyone".
2. Distribute: a (per-determined) user i_0 has a message m_j for ever other user j!=i_0. The length of the messages is a public constant value. It is a little similar to broadcast but the receivers are not receiving the same message.
3. Gather:  a (per-determined) user i_0 receives a message m_j from ever other user j!=i_0. The length of the messages is a public constant value. This is very similar to vote mechanism.

Besides, there are also a small amount of two-party communication between some of the users.

The round-trip cost is very sensitive in the application. Thus a one-roundtrip implementation for these communication patterns is very desirable.

Besides, the bandwidth cost of the application is very high thus a non-blocking implementation is almost a must-have.

I first tried the classic server/client socket (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/) by having multiply ports and deploy a server/client pair between every two users. However it turns out to be a failure.

I also investgate the ZMQ library. But to my poor understanding I have to somehow handle "routing" on my own, which I am not capable of.

Nanomsg is another candidate to go with but none of the patterns it provides seem to match the requirements.

So, could anyone provide any idea about this challenge? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not 127 people?

Comment: It can be 127 people. Just want to give some idea about the scale.